# Press a key every 10 seconds

Tags: java, button, awtrobot

Im trying to make a program that will punch the F1 key every 10 seconds, As far as I can see most of it is correct except im getting a error message displaying "unreported Exception AWTException; Must be caught or declared to be thrown" on line 14 with 'new Robot();' underlined as being wrong.

Can anyone help?`

```
package textreader;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class TextReader {


public static void main(String[] args)  throws AWTException{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         public void run(){ 
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
         }
    }, 0, 5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to surround `Robot r = new Robot()` with `try { Robot r = new Robot()} catch(AWTException e) { // Catch block }`.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `Robot` object inside the `run` method, not the main method. This is why you're getting the error. Since the `run` method doesn't allow you to specifiy exceptions thrown by calling the method, you're going to have to surround the definition inside of a [try/catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block.

```
try{
    Robot r = new Robot();
    //These lines will also have to be put inside the try block as they
    //rely on the robot object
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F1);**strong text**
} catch (AWTException exception){
    //Log exception
}
```

This will get rid of your error. Also, remove `throws AWTException` from the main method.